# ASP Core: NullReferenceException in ApiController.ExecuteAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using ASP.NET Core application with WebAPI template and all existing controllers are inherited from `System.Web.Http.ApiController`.
So, requests ends with error that pointed to NRE in method `ExecuteAsync`. Stack stace of this exception is shown below:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionFilterAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.<RequestProcessingAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Interesting moment I found overrides ExecuteAsync method: controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor property has empty value (null) and base implementation of ExecuteAsync throws this exception trying to execute code

```
ServicesContainer services = controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.Configuration.Services;
```

[image: Controller state]

Another intersting moment for me is debug log message:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector: Debug: Action 'WebAPI.Controllers.AuthController.Post (WebAPI)' with id '9848905d-176e-44bc-9453-53c5185b46c6' did not match the constraint
```

Full debug message stack is shown below:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:64513/api/auth application/json; charset=utf-8 0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter: Debug: Request successfully matched the route with name '' and template 'api/auth'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector: Debug: Action 'WebAPI.Controllers.AuthController.Post (WebAPI)' with id '9848905d-176e-44bc-9453-53c5185b46c6' did not match the constraint 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.HttpMethodActionConstraint'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Debug: Executing action WebAPI.Controllers.AuthController.ExecuteAsync (WebAPI)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Executing action method WebAPI.Controllers.AuthController.ExecuteAsync (WebAPI) with arguments (System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken) - ModelState is Valid
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in System.Web.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in mscorlib.dll
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel: Error: Connection id "0HL06UADGPFB4": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
```

Controller's actions are marked with AspNetCore.Mvc HTTP method attributes but it was not a problem for application before:

```
using BodyObject = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FromBodyAttribute;
using OPTIONS = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpOptionsAttribute;
using POST = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpPostAttribute;
[OPTIONS, POST]
public async Task<PostResponse> Post([BodyObject] PostRequest model)
```

I'm confused what is the real root of the problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

*// Some another linees of code, I think, have to be shown there for better understanding of the problem:*

project.json dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.0"
  },
```

Startup.RegisterServices

```
services.AddMvc(options => { /* some filters add code */ });
services.AddRouting();
```

Startup.Configure

```
#if DEBUG
loggerFactory.AddDebug((a, b) => true);
#endif
app.UseMvc();
app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());

if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

Comment: You should be deriving from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller` or use the WebApi compat shim (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim/1.0.0) if you'd like to use the WebApi pattern. `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` isn't intended to be used with Asp.Net Core.

Answer (score 1):

Well, thanks to **Pranav** for his response.
For some reason the alpha-version of MVC/WebAPI controllers mix worked well. But life is a complicated thing and there were a problems related to the `Controller` and `ApiController` incompatibility. The only solution was to remove all `AspCore.WebApi` relations and install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim` package.